# TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation | Coding a simple calculator

Tags: python

I'm trying to code a simple calculator.

Below is the Updated code. But still same error.

```
running = True   
while running:
        print("1 Addition \
            2 Subtraction \
            3 Multiplication \
            4 Division \
            5 remainder \
            6 Power of \
            7 Quit")

        O = int(input('What Operaton you want to do ? '))
        F = float(input('Enter first number: '))
        S = float(input('Enter Second number: '))

        if O == 1:
            R = F + S
            print(F,'+',S,'=',R)
        elif O == 2:
            R = F - S
            print(F,'-',S,'=',R)
        elif O == 3:
            R = F * S
            print(F,'*',S,'=',R)
        elif O == 4:
            R = F / S
            print(F,'/',S,'=',R)
        elif O == 5:
            R = F % S
            print(F,'%',S,'=',R)
        elif O == 6:
            R = F ** S
            print(F,'**',S,'=',R)
        else:
            print('Quit')
            running = False
```

And while running I'm facing the Below error.

$/usr/local/bin/python3.7 file1.py
     File "file1.py", line 20
        R = F - S            ^
    TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: The error message is telling you pretty clearly what the problem is.

Comment: The error is from the `while` being indented when it shouldn't be

Comment: Moreover, there is error in `else O ==7` use `elif O==7` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're indenting your `while` statement unnecessarily.

```
running = True   
    while running:
```

should be:

```
running = True   
while running:
```

There is another problem though:

Instead of:

```
else O == 7:
    print('Quit')
    running = False
```

You should write:

```
else:
    print('Quit')
    running = False
```

`else` doesn't take any argument. It is simple the set of statements chosen when no `if` or `elif` condition is true.